# Updating already published collection in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to understand how to REpublish in Meteor. I have this published "allCustomers" data which gets loaded initially on page load, with the customers from current month:

```
Meteor.publish("allCustomers", function () {

  var pDate = moment().utc().toDate();
  var dateFilter = GetWholeMonthFilterFromDate(pDate);      
  return Customers.find(dateFilter); 
});
```

All good so far. I also have this server method that gets customers when the user selects a *different* month than the current one:

```
Meteor.methods({
    allCustomers:function(pDate){

    function GetWholeMonthFilterFromDate(pDate){
      var firstDayOfMonth = new Date(pDate.getFullYear(), pDate.getMonth(), 1);
      var lastDayOfMonth = new Date(pDate.getFullYear(), pDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);

      var dateFilter = 
      {
        "joined": {"$gte": firstDayOfMonth, "$lte": lastDayOfMonth} 
      };
      return dateFilter;
    }

    var dateFilter = GetWholeMonthFilterFromDate(pDate);      
    return Customers.find(dateFilter).fetch(); 
},
```

I use this "allCustomers" server method like this:

```
Meteor.call("allCustomers", selectedDate, function(error, result){
        if(error)
        {
            console.log('ERROR :', error);
            return;
        }
        else
            console.log(result);
});
```

My question is, when the user selects a different date, how do I use the resultset from the Meteor.call("allCustomers") to update the initial published "allCustomer" data? Meaning, even if I do see the new customers in the console (as the callback executes), my page is still using the old data from the initial publishing. How do I re-update the published data with the result of the Meteor.call() ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to resubscribe to `allCustomers`, which needs little improvement:

```
Meteor.publish("allCustomers", function (pDate) {
  var dateFilter = GetWholeMonthFilterFromDate(pDate);      
  return Customers.find(dateFilter); 
});
```

Your `allCustomers` publish function was modified by adding parameter `pDate` which is much more flexible than creating `pDate` inside.

In this approach you **stop subscription** and **subscribe** again with param `pDate`.

```
// UPDATED after @saimeunt comment 

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.startup(function(){
        Tracker.autorun(function(){
          Meteor.subscribe('allCustomers',Session.get("selectedDate"));      
        })
        // initial selection
        Session.set("selectedDate",moment().utc().toDate());
    })
}
```

Remember to change date in `Session.set("selectedDate", DATE_PARAM)` menu template:

```
Template.tpl_name.events({
  'click .month':function(e, tpl){
    var DATE_PARAM = ... ;
    Session.set("selectedDate", DATE_PARAM)
  }
})
```

Everytime user will click on `.month` button `Session.get("selectedDate")` will be changed and that will cause resubscription.

[Example showing this approach](https://github.com/parhelium/laboratory/commit/2b5c63d371f2fad33aa29af5816b13a2bc8b14ed)

Comment: thank you - i tried this but i get "Tracker is not defined". Is this something that was introduced in the latest Meteor version? My project still runs on Meteor 0.8.3

Comment: i changed Tracker with Deps and it seems to work; is it OK to do this replacement?

Comment: Yes, Deps is deprecated since Meteor 0.9.x.

Comment: FYI, there is no need to manually `stop` the subscription handle because `Meteor.subscribe` is called whithin an autorun. http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe